# Android Studio, on Windows: ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I downloaded Android Studio on windows, and I am trying to run the default HelloWorld application. However, when I run that app, I get a dialog box with the following:

```
ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'
```

I've searched for solutions online and most of it was to kill the adb server and start it again manually, but when I do so in the command line I get:

```
sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server
* server not running *

sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
adb server is out of date.  killing...
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
```

And the first error keeps showing. I restarted my machine, and the problem is still there. Any ideas? Thanks.

I tried this fix: http://visualgdb.com/adbfix/#adbfix_download but it did not work. It showed: `"No Conflicts Found".`

**Note:** I need the app to run on my device. Not on emulator

Comment: No, I am using Nexus 5

Comment: I didn't try it, but I'd give this a try: http://visualgdb.com/adbfix/

Comment: I tried that, and it did not work. It showed "No conflicts found"

Comment: `adb server is out of date` is indicative of multiple conflicting versions of `adb` installed. Find and remove all copies but the most recent version. Make sure that all tools are able to use that one.

Comment: I deleted every adb.exe and the two files that come with it, from my machine except the ones in the platform tools which is being used by the Android Studio. Still, the problem was not solved.

Comment: uzip the content of https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r21-windows.zip into `platform-tools` folder

Comment: I fixed it by opening task manager, and stopping all processes that has to do with ADB. The specific one was some ADB_Helper process.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue and I followed these steps and problem went away:

1.close all program in your system then

2.then go to start button and search for `%temp%` then delete all files inside this folder

3.install Cclean software and clean your system.

4.restart your system

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in win7 and I took these steps to resolve the problem:

When starting Android Studio, it warns you with `ADB not responding`. 
If you'd like to retry, then please manually `kill` the process. You should enter `cmd`, and input `adb kill-server` for ten times or more.

When the building has finished, input `adb start-server` and you will see

```
daemon not running. 
starting it now on port 5037 
daemon started successfully
```